# How to hide default switch "on/off" text in Maui?

Tags: maui

I have a switch control in .Net Maui :

```
<Switch IsToggled="true" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
```

By default it shows a label "on/off" based on it's state. I want it to show nothing.

Is there any way to hide/remove it?

[image]

Comment: Search https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues to see if there is any discussion of this. [OPINION] That's a bizarre choice for default behavior. Maybe that's WinUI's default (?), but WinUI also has `OffContent` and `OnContent` properties, that I see are missing in Maui. Lacking those, Maui should suppress the text.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately the Maui switch control have **SwitchOnVisualState** \ **SwitchOffVisualState** content set to constant strings and you can't override it yet apparently.

You can however override the ToggleSwitch class style in WinUI through the App.xaml file.

**Project**\Platforms\Windows\App.xaml

It should look like this.

```
 <maui:MauiWinUIApplication
      x:Class="Project.Client.WinUI.App"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:maui="using:Microsoft.Maui"
      xmlns:local="using:Project.Client.WinUI">
      <maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
      <ResourceDictionary>
        <!-- ToggleSwitch : Turn off ON/OFF label -->
        <Style TargetType="ToggleSwitch">
            <Setter Property="OffContent" Value=" " />
            <Setter Property="OnContent" Value=" " />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,-110,0" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources> 
</maui:MauiWinUIApplication>
```

See?

[image]

Comment: doesnt work as of now, "cant resolve type ToggleSwitch". If changed to "Switch" -- "cant resolve property "OffContent"

Comment: This is not correct. There is no ToggleSwitch control nor does the Switch control have a OffContent or OnContent property to style like @MikeTsayper said.

Answer (score 3):

Please check the solution for this issue here https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6177
I have tried one solution and it is working
I have used Absolute Layout. As Absolute Layout gives you option to specify child's width . I have given 60 as width for the Switch controll. And it show only the Switch not On/Off text next to it.
And also checked by resizing the window , all is working fine. The On/Off Text doesn't Appear.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way to work-around it as of .Net 8:

```
.ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
{
#if WINDOWS
    SwitchHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("Custom", (h, _) =>
    {
        h.PlatformView.OffContent = string.Empty;
        h.PlatformView.OnContent = string.Empty;

        h.PlatformView.MinWidth = 0;
    });
#endif
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FreakySwitch, it's made out of SkiaSharp and lets you customize it to the dot, also its design is Material 3 switch for Android and Generic iOS design for iOS.

Github: https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls

Namespace:

```
xmlns:freakyControls="clr-namespace:Maui.FreakyControls;assembly=Maui.FreakyControls"
```

Usage:

```
 <freakyControls:FreakySwitch
     OffColor="Blue"
     ThumbOffColor="SkyBlue"
     OnColor="Pink"
     ThumbOnColor="Yellow" />
```